# How to fetch UPS Delivery Progress through their APIs?

Tags: php, api, ups

I found a couple of PHP Classes online that utilizes the UPS Tracking API, but the problem is that I don't get the whole route... I only get the status (saying if it was already delivered or not -- along with a lot more info that I don't need for what I'm doing).

I know it's possible because I see a lot of sites doing it all the time such as this one:

http://www.packagetrackr.com/track/1Z0766Y54242241130

(Not to mention eBay, Amazon, etc).

Again I am using the UPS Tracking API with the following URL:
https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track (along with the XML payloads, etc)

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! UPS have a section about API use [link](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_US), you will need to register an account there and request an API key, as described on that page. Here is a page which allows you to see what APIs they have available [link](https://www.ups.com/content/us/en/resources/sri/apidefinition.html) and there are also many other resources on their website which you can use for help.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your tip. I actually already have an account with UPS and already went over their Docs. I just can't find the API that I can use to get the Shipping Progress (line by line) of a certain package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's no standard way of getting statues, you'll have to parse the UPS website

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php 

class upstraking 
{
    function upstrack($trackingno,$account_data)
    {
        $trackingno='1Z12345E1512345676';
        $data ="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
        <AccessRequest xml:lang='en-US'>
        <AccessLicenseNumber>".$account_data['access_lic_no']."</AccessLicenseNumber>
        <UserId>".$account_data['username']."</UserId>
        <Password>".$account_data['password']."</Password>
        </AccessRequest>
        <?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
        <TrackRequest>
        <Request>
        <TransactionReference>
        <CustomerContext>
        <InternalKey>blah</InternalKey>
        </CustomerContext>
        <XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>
        </TransactionReference>
        <RequestAction>Track</RequestAction>
        </Request>
        <TrackingNumber>$trackingno</TrackingNumber>
        </TrackRequest>";
        $ch = curl_init("https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
        $result=curl_exec ($ch);
        // echo '<!-- '. $result. ' -->';
        $data = strstr($result, '<?');
        $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
        xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $data, $vals, $index);
        xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
        $params = array();
        $level = array();
        #print_r($vals);#die();
        foreach ($vals as $xml_elem) {
        if ($xml_elem['type'] == 'open') {
            if (array_key_exists('attributes',$xml_elem)) {
                    list($level[$xml_elem['level']],$extra) = array_values($xml_elem['attributes']);
            } else {
                    $level[$xml_elem['level']] = $xml_elem['tag'];
            }
        }
        if ($xml_elem['type'] == 'complete') {
            if(isset($xml_elem['value']) && $xml_elem['value'] != '') {
                $start_level = 1;
                $php_stmt = '$params';
                while($start_level < $xml_elem['level']) {
                    $php_stmt .= '[$level['.$start_level.']]';
                    $start_level++;
                }
                $php_stmt .= '[$xml_elem[\'tag\']] = $xml_elem[\'value\'];';
                eval($php_stmt);
            }

     }
}
curl_close($ch);
//return $params;

    print_r($params); // this array will return full information of tracking

//die();
$table = "";
$table .= "<table class='pure-table pure-table-horizontal' border='1'>";
$table .= "<th>PIN</th>";
$table .= "<th>Date</th>";
$table .= "<th>Description</th>";
$table .= "<th>Address</th>";
//$table .= "<th>Signatory Name</th>";
//$table .= "<th>Event Type</th>";
$table .= "</tr>";

if($params['TRACKRESPONSE']['RESPONSE']['RESPONSESTATUSDESCRIPTION']=='Success')
{
    $shipment=$params['TRACKRESPONSE']['SHIPMENT'];
    $address_arr=$shipment['PACKAGE']['ACTIVITY']['ACTIVITYLOCATION']['ADDRESS'];
    $address=$address_arr['CITY'].', '.$address_arr['STATEPROVINCECODE'].', '.$address_arr['COUNTRYCODE'];

    $table .= "<tr>";
    $table .= "<td>".$shipment['PACKAGE']['TRACKINGNUMBER']."</td>";
    $table .= "<td>".$shipment['PACKAGE']['ACTIVITY']['DATE'] . "</td>";
    $table .= "<td>".$shipment['PACKAGE']['ACTIVITY']['STATUS']['STATUSTYPE']['DESCRIPTION'] . "</td>";
    $table .= "<td>".$address."</td>";

    $table .= "</tr>";
}

$table .= "</table>";
echo $table;
    }
}


$obj_upstraking = new upstraking();
$account_data = array();
$account_data['access_lic_no']='accesskey';
$account_data['username']='upsusername';
$account_data['password']='password';
$obj_upstraking->upstrack($trackingno='1Z12345E1512345676',$account_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following to display line by line UPS status for my customers on our site.

```
 $tracking_url = 'http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums='.$insert_tracking_number_here;
 include('simple_html_dom.php');
 $html = file_get_html($tracking_url);
 foreach($html->find('th') as $e)
        $e->outertext = '';
        $html->save();
        $method = $html->find('a.service', 0)->innertext;
        echo 'Your Order #: '.$ordernumber.' was shipped on '.$shipdate.' via '.$method.'.<P></P>';
        $delivery_check = $html->find('dt', 0)->innertext;
        $is_delivered = strpos($delivery_check, 'Delivered On');
        $delivery = $html->find('dd', 8)->innertext;
        if ($is_delivered===false) {
            echo '<b>Scheduled delivery: '.$delivery.'.</b><P></P>';
        } else {
            echo '<b>Delivered on: '.$delivery.'</b><P></P>';
        }
        echo 'Below is the current information for tracking number '.$tracking.'.<P></P><br>'; ?>
        <table border="0"><tr><td colspan="6"><hr></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="text10b" width="230">LOCATION</td>
        <td class="text10b" width="80">DATE</td>
        <td class="text10b" width="100">LOCAL TIME</td>
        <td class="text10b" width="230">ACTIVITY</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="6"><hr></td></tr>
        <?php foreach($html->find('table.dataTable') as $service) echo $service->innertext;?>
        <tr><td colspan="6"><hr></td></tr></table>
```